# JavaScript How to edit a button (Make him bigger)

Tags: javascript, css, button, move

I want to make my button bigger with JavaScript. How can i do this?

I tried it so:

```
var signin = document.getElementById("signin");
signin.style.width = "400px";
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: `document.getElementById("test").style.width="400px";` Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q5faq941/

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle or more information.

Comment: document.getElementById("signin").style.width="400px" doesn't work :/

Comment: That should work @LordSpigot. Check if your id is correct

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: @LordSpigot When you post a problem, especially one without enough detail to really answer (like this one), you should really stay on top of comments and answers. Otherwise people will get bored and go away, possibly after downvoting or voting to close, and never come back.

Comment: @torazaburo I cant speak english well, im sry :/

Comment: I'm not referring to English; I'm referring to reacting quickly to questions and comments.

Comment: @torazaburo Yeah i know what you mean, but i dont know what i sould write...would you are a German, i can tell you much more ^^

Comment: @LordSpigot All I'm trying to say is, two hours ago, a comment was posted, asking "What does the console say?", but you haven't answered that yet. I don't think this is a language problem. What does the console say?

Comment: Yeah, torazaburo's point is correct. @LordSpigot you should put other codes there

Answer (score 0):

A test case : it Works !

```js
var enlarge = function(){
var signin = document.getElementById("signin");
signin.style.width = "400px";
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div><span>click to sign in</span>
  </div>
  <button id='signin' onclick='enlarge()'>Sign In</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Why do you think the OP's code doesn't work?

Comment: @torazaburo : people who just saying 'it works' don't convince him, with the snippet he can see that it works and maybe he can understand  that the problem come from his code and he can compare his with this one